# How to start Zookeper

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-zookeeper

I am unable to start zookpeer to further start Kafka.
My folder structure is:

- Root

  - bin

    - zookeper-server-start.sh
  - config

    - zookeper.properties

I have tried running

```
./zookeeper-server-start.sh ../config/zookeeper.properties
```

And i get the following error:

```
/d/Programs/Kafka/kafka_2.12-2.2.0/bin/kafka-run-class.sh: line 306: C:\Program: No such file or directory
```

**Code executed that generates error**

```
exec $JAVA $KAFKA_HEAP_OPTS $KAFKA_JVM_PERFORMANCE_OPTS $KAFKA_GC_LOG_OPTS $KAFKA_JMX_OPTS $KAFKA_LOG4J_OPTS -cp $CLASSPATH $KAFKA_OPTS "$@"
```

When running `java version` i get:

```
> java version "1.8.0_211" Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build
> 1.8.0_211-b12) Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.211-b12, mixed mode)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like a classpath issue:
Make sure that Java is defined correctly.
Check what exactly happens in `kafka-run-class.sh line 306`, the chances are that you'll see something like this:

`exec $JAVA $KAFKA_HEAP_OPTS $KAFKA_JVM_PERFORMANCE_OPTS $KAFKA_GC_LOG_OPTS $KAFKA_JMX_OPTS $KAFKA_LOG4J_OPTS -cp $CLASSPATH $KAFKA_OPTS "$@"`

So this is a Java invocation line. If you've installed java in "Program Files" (a folder with a space) you'll need to enclose the Env Variable that points to java with double quotes.

- check JAVA_HOME env variable
- check PATH env evariable

Comment: I have just installed java  in the default path `C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_211` and set the environment  variable `%JAVA_HOME%` with the path in the user variables , and added it to the system variables.I also added what happens at that line.

Comment: Maybe 'program files' space issue. Try to run with config full path instead of relative.

Edit: i see u use d/programs but sh search for c/program, maybe you should look into the script.

Comment: @BercoviciAdrian: yes, that's what we're talking about exactly. open cmd and type : java -version. If you have an error, you should fix that first before running zookeeper...